# Spark SparseVector trim down zero elements

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I know that normally there should not have any zero elements in Spark `SparseVector`, as it is represent by default value(`0.0`), but in the case where I create a `SparseVector` with below code:

```
In : Vectors.sparse(5, [0, 1, 3, 5], [0.0, 1, 2, 0.0])
Out: SparseVector(5, {0: 0.0, 1: 1.0, 3: 2.0, 5: 0.0})
```

Then I can have a `SparseVector` that contains zero elements.

My problem is how can I remove the zero elements that can be represent by default values from above, into below `SparseVector` as shown below:

```
SparseVector(5, {1: 1.0, 3: 2.0})
```

Besides, is the zero elements in the `SparseVector` taking any any space? or it is actually also representing by the default values as well in `SparseVector` implementation?

Comment: About why I create such a `SparseVector` with zeros:  the source data  (a dict to an array by throwing all its keys away) contains many zeros and I cant not figure out the positions of its zeros and keeping their indexes intact in the same time)

Answer (score 3):

For example like this:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors, SparseVector, DenseVector

def drop_zeros(x):
    """
    >>> drop_zeros(DenseVector([1.0, 0.0]))
    SparseVector(2, {0: 1.0})
    >>> drop_zeros(SparseVector(3, {0: 0.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 0.0}))
    SparseVector(3, {1: 2.0})
    """
    if isinstance(x, SparseVector):
        return SparseVector(
            x.size, {i: v for i, v in zip(x.indices, x.values) if v})
    if isinstance(x, DenseVector):
        return SparseVector(
            len(x), {i: v for i, v in enumerate(x.array) if v})
    raise TypeError("Invalid type {0}".format(type(x)))

sparse_with_zeros = Vectors.sparse(5, [0, 1, 3, 5], [0.0, 1, 2, 0.0])
drop_zeros(sparse_with_zeros)

## SparseVector(5, {1: 1.0, 3: 2.0})

dense_with_zeros = DenseVector([1.0, 3.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0])
## SparseVector(5, {0: 1.0, 1: 3.0, 3: 2.0})
```

In Scala, the simplest approach is to use `toSparse` method:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vectors, DenseVector, SparseVector}

val sparse_with_zeros = Vectors.sparse(3, Array(0, 1, 2), Array(0.0, 1.0, 0.0))
sparse_with_zeros.toSparse
// org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector = (3,[1],[1.0])
```

> Besides, is the zero elements in the SparseVector taking any any space? or it is actually also representing by the default values as well in SparseVector implementation?

If vector is explicitly created with zero indices then these zero elements take space.